# Bootstrap Navbar not collapsing on mobile or tablet

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im having problems with my Bootstrap not collapsing down. I'm not sure why its not working.
hope someone can be of help thanks. I am a newbie so please be gentle.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="smoothScroll" href="#work">Work</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="smoothScroll" href="#team">Team</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="smoothScroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Are you referencing the correct javascript and css files? Does it work on a desktop?

Comment: Please check version of Jquery and Boostrap version, sometimes it does not work correct with some versions

Comment: You have almost certainly missed references to JS/CSS files, your code [works fine](http://www.bootply.com/iTKEB0Uiop)

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't included the bootstrap.js file. It has the code to make the navbar collapse work. It is the most common mistake that newbies face. I know I did.

[Another case where the navbar collapse did not work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26659791/navbar-collapse-not-working-bootstrap-github/26659893#26659893)

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, the most likely cause is you are missing the relevant javascript and css files.

The HTML appears to be fine, and although you say it doesn't work on a phone or tablet, I'd suspect if you shrink the browser width, it too won't work on a desktop.

Adding the relevant CSS and javascript files will resolve this issue.

**Update**

Based upon the comments of this post, the issue was an "old version of jquery."

Comment: Thanks An old version of jquery was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Code like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="smoothScroll" href="#work">Work</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="smoothScroll" href="#team">Team</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="smoothScroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
    </form>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```